# Return multiple objects from an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to fetch data from an Oracle database with Dapper ORM in .NET 6.0.

This is the code to fetch the data:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/GetDatas")]
public object GetDatas(string? nom = null, string? pre = null)
{
    var queryResult = userRepository.GetDatas(nom, pre);

    var totalResult = userRepository.GetDatasFullQueryResult(nom, pre);

    int timeStamp = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1,1))).TotalSeconds;

    if (queryResult == null)
    {
        return NotFound(Tools.returnError("erreur lors de la récuperation des flux avocats, endpoint: api/GetDatas")); 
    }

    return Ok(queryResult); // here my problem
}
```

I have result in each variable (`queryResult`, `totalResult`, `timeStamp`) and I want to construct a json response like this:

```json
{
    "metadata": 
        [
            {
                "totalResult": "2",
                "timestamp": "1673347991"
            }
        ],
    "fiche_avocats": 
        [
            {
                "nom": "doe",
                "pre": "john"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "nom": "foo",
                "pre": "bar"
            }
        ]
}
```

I tried to use a `Tuple` native type, but the result is like `item1: [1673347991]`..

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Thery

Comment: where is the problem? either create model for your json or use anonymous classes for this ...

Comment: `Data` is one of those words in English that is singular and plural at the same time - there really isn't "datas" as a word ....

Comment: There's no Dapper or any database-related code in the question. `return Ok(queryResult);` has nothing to do with databases anyway - MVC/WebAPI will serialize whatever `queryResult` contains as JSON, even if it's a string. If you want to return some *other* object, create that other object. You can use an anonymous type to combine other objects into one if you want

Comment: An action should return either a specific object type or `IActionResult` (or a derived type), not `object`. Change the return type to `IActionResult` and return an object in the shape you want, eg `return new {totalResult,timestamp,queryResult};` or `new {metadata=new[]{new {totalResult,timestamp}}, whatever=queryResult}`. It's a *lot* easier to create a concrete class for the result, especially if it's complex

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution :

```
  [HttpGet]

  [Route("api/GetDatas")]

  public object GetDatas()
  {
     List<object>  listObj = new  List<object>();

     var queryResult = ....................;

     var totalResult = ....................;

     int timeStamp =.......................;

     listObj.Add(queryResult);

     listObj.Add(totalResult);

     listObj.Add(timeStamp);

   return Json(listObj);
   }
```